# Descriptive statistics term

Tags: statistics, terminology, regression, descriptive-statistics

I have statistical results that I am including in a single table.  Those results are the following four procedures:  $R^{2}$, coefficient of variance (CV), root MSE (mean standard error), and the mean.  I have labeled the table as "Variance" but I don't feel that this is the appropriate term for these four statistical results.  Does anybody have a different descriptor I could use?

I am also, in two other tables, using results from a one-way ANOVA and, in the other table, Tukey's Studentized Range.

I am literally seeking a title for my table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one - maybe "Goodness of fit" would be an appropriate choice.
For the ANOVA table, well, ANOVA\Analysis of Variance is the standard name for such a table. For the last one - "Multiple Comparisons" or something like that.